# How are 1x1 convolutions the same as a fully connected layer?

Tags: neural-network, convolutional-neural-network

I recently read [Yan LeCuns comment on 1x1 convolutions](https://www.facebook.com/yann.lecun/posts/10152820758292143):

> **In Convolutional Nets, there is no such thing as "fully-connected layers". There are only convolution layers with 1x1 convolution kernels and a full connection table.**
>
> It's a too-rarely-understood fact that ConvNets don't need to have a fixed-size input.
>
> You can train them on inputs that happen to produce a single output vector (with no spatial extent), and then apply them to larger images.
>
> Instead of a single output vector, you then get a spatial map of output vectors.  Each vector sees input windows at different locations on the input.
> **In that scenario, the "fully connected layers" really act as 1x1 convolutions.**

I would like to see a simple example for this.

### Example

Assume you have a fully connected network. It has only an input layer and an
output layer. The input layer has 3 nodes, the output layer has 2 nodes. This
network has $3 \cdot 2 = 6$ parameters. To make it even more concrete, lets say you have a ReLU activation function in the output layer and the weight matrix

$$
\begin{align}
W &= 
\begin{pmatrix}
 0 & 1 & 1\\
 2 & 3 & 5\\
\end{pmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^{2 \times 3}\\
b &= \begin{pmatrix}8\\ 13\end{pmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^2
\end{align}
$$

So the network is $f(x) = ReLU(W \cdot x + b)$ with $x \in \mathbb{R}^3$.

**How would the convolutional layer have to look like to be the same? What does LeCun mean with "full connection table"?**

I guess to get an equivalent CNN it would have to have exactly the same number of parameters. The MLP from above has $2 \cdot 3 + 2 = 8$ parameters.

Comment: This may clear it up https://sebastianraschka.com/faq/docs/fc-to-conv.html

Comment: Thanks for the resource @Joffer. It includes the modalities of natural language, images, and code together to avoid the split attention effect. It's also clear there are two ways to convert a CONV layer to a FC layer; LeCun is only talking about it's second method (though he suggests training on small images and running inference on large images, no flatten step).

Answer (score 43, accepted):

### Your Example

In your example we have 3 input and 2 output units. To apply convolutions, think of those units having shape: `[1,1,3]` and `[1,1,2]`, respectively. In CNN terms, we have `3` input and `2` output feature maps, each having spatial dimensions `1 x 1`.

Applying an `n x n` convolution to a layer with `k` feature maps, requires you to have a kernel of shape `[n,n,k]`. Hence the kernel of your `1x1` convolutions have shape `[1, 1, 3]`. You need `2` of those kernels (or filters) to produce the `2` output feature maps. Please Note: $1 \times 1$ convolutions really are  $1 \times 1 \times \text{number of channels of the input}$ convolutions. The last one is only rarely mentioned.

Indeed if you choose as kernels and bias:
$$
\begin{align}
w_1 &= 
\begin{pmatrix}
 0 & 1 & 1\\
\end{pmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^{3}\\
w_2 &= 
\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 3 & 5\\
\end{pmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^{3}\\
b &= \begin{pmatrix}8\\ 13\end{pmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^2
\end{align}
$$

The conv-layer will then compute $f(x) = ReLU\left(\begin{pmatrix}w_1 \cdot x\\ w_2 \cdot x\end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix}b_1\\ b_2\end{pmatrix}\right)$ with $x \in \mathbb{R}^3$.

### Transformation in real Code

For a real-life example, also have a look at my [vgg-fcn](https://github.com/MarvinTeichmann/tensorflow-fcn/blob/d04bc268ac6e84f03afc4332d7f54ecff22d1732/fcn32_vgg.py) implementation. The Code provided in this file takes the VGG weights, but transforms every fully-connected layer into a convolutional layers. The resulting network yields the same output as `vgg` when applied to input image of shape `[244,244,3]`. (When applying both networks without padding).

The transformed convolutional layers are introduced in the function `_fc_layer` (line 145). They have kernel size `7x7` for FC6 (which is maximal, as `pool5` of VGG outputs a feature map of shape `[7,7, 512]`. Layer `FC7` and `FC8` are implemented as `1x1` convolution.

### "Full Connection Table"

He might refer to a filter/kernel which has the same dimension as the input feature map. In both cases (Code and your Example) the spatial dimensions are maximal in the sense, that the spatial dimension of the filter is the same as the spatial dimension as the input.

Comment: "Hence the kernel of you 1x1 convolutions have shape [1, 1, 3].". What? There seems to be a bigger misunderstanding of convolutions. I thought if a  convolution kernel has shape [1, 1, 3], then one would say it is a 1x1x3 convolution? So 1x1 convolution is only about the output, not about the kernel?

Comment: For me `kernel = filter`, do you agree?
>> "So 1x1 convolution is only about the output, not about the kernel? 
Not at all. A `3x3` convolution can have an arbitrary output shape. " Indeed, if padding is used and `stride=1` then the `output shape = input shape`.
>> "I thought if a convolution kernel has shape [1, 1, 3], then one would say it is a 1x1x3 convolution?"
No, I have never heared someone talking about `3x3x512` convolutions. However all convolution-filters I have seen have a third spatial dimension equal to the number of feature-maps of the input layer.

Comment: For reference, have a look at the `Convolution Demo` of Karpathies CS321n course: http://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/#conv. Or at the tensorflow API: https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/api_docs/python/nn.html#conv2d
Filters are supposed to have shape  `[filter_height, filter_width, in_channels, out_channels]`.

Comment: May I add the thing with "1x1 convolutions are 1 x 1 x number of channels of the input" to your answer? This was the source of my confusion and I keep forgetting this.

Comment: Sure, go ahead!

Comment: @MartinThoma, I think you added the comment on the wrong paragraph. The first paragraph descripes the shapes of the input/output layer. Although they have spatial dimension `1 x 1` in your example, this is not directly related to the `1 x 1` convolution. I think the comment would fit better in the second paragraph, which talks about the convolution itself.

Comment: You're right. However, it is your answer. Go ahead and change it to whatever you think is good. I only wanted to have this stated explicitly as this was the part which was important for me to read.

Comment: But why do we need to convert fully connected layers to 1x1 convolutions? Why not to train just with 1x1 convolutions? or output blob shape will be different? Why this trick work at all https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/examples/net_surgery.ipynb ?

Comment: @mrgloom: to train a fully convolutional network, like FCN8s for example

Comment: Just for reference, the FCs in TensorFlow slim are implemented as 2D convolutions: " Note: All the fully_connected layers have been transformed to conv2d layers." `net = layers.conv2d(
          net,
          num_classes, [1, 1],
          activation_fn=None,
          normalizer_fn=None,
          scope='fc8')`

Comment: But if the input feature map has different size (e.g. pool5 output), then the filter/kernel size also need to change to match the input feature size. But once trained, the filter size cannot change, right? Then why "ConvNets don't need to have a fixed-size input"?

Comment: these FCN implementations in Caffe (the original implementation) and pytorch may be useful https://github.com/wkentaro/pytorch-fcn https://github.com/shelhamer/fcn.berkeleyvision.org

Comment: I don't believe this is right... You can't just take inputs and treat them as feature maps (depth). You could have several feature maps of ```nxn``` pixel inputs, and in that case a ```1x1``` convolution won't have the same output as a fully connected layer. The latter multiplies **each** input (pixel) of **each** feature map by a different weight. Whereas the former would multiply **each** feature map by a different weight, but not **each** input.

Answer (score 6):

A fully connected layer (for input size $n*n$ over with $i$ channels, and $m$ output neurons) IS NOT equivalent to a 1x1 convolution layer but rather to an $n$x$n$ convolution layer (i.e. a big kernel, same size as input- no pad) with number of filters equal to the FC output/hidden layer (i.e. $m$ filters)

As you asked, it has the same number of parameters as the FCN, i.e. $n*n*i*m$ (plus bias):

FCN: $n*n*i$ (weights per input layer= input$*$channels) $* m$ (times output/hidden layer width)

CNN: $n*n$ (each kernel) $* i $ (kernel per input channel) $* m$ (number of filters)

([Source](https://www.quora.com/Is-a-fully-connected-neural-network-conceptually-similar-to-a-1x1-convolutional-neural-network))

Comment: Of course these two things are equivalent in the special case $n=1$; I think that's where the confusion comes in.

Comment: @YiboYang I believe he is definitely right. A ```1x1``` convolution would share the same single weight across the input space.

Answer (score 2):

The equivalent kernel simply has whatever shape the input has, and computes a tensor dot product. (I use the word "shape" as there seems to be some confusion over "size", which often ignores the channel/depth dimension). There's no "sliding the kernel across input" involved, since the kernel is as large as it can be.
Quoting [Stanford CS 231n course notes](http://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/#convert):

> any FC layer can be converted to a CONV layer. For example, an FC
>   layer with K=4096 that is looking at some input volume of size 7×7×512
>   can be equivalently expressed as a CONV layer with
>   F=7,P=0,S=1,K=4096,F=7,P=0,S=1,K=4096. In other words, we are setting
>   the filter size to be exactly the size of the input volume, and hence
>   the output will simply be 1×1×4096 since only a single depth
>   column “fits” across the input volume, giving identical result as the
>   initial FC layer.

I believe "F=7,P=0,S=1,K=4096,F=7,P=0,S=1,K=4096" here means each conv kernel has shape 7x7x512, and there's 4096 such filters.

The earlier answer mentioned that the last fc of AlexNet (which receives input with shape 1x1x4096 and computes 1000 class scores) is implemented as "1x1 convolution". To be complete, each such conv kernel has **shape** 1x1x4096, and there's 1000 of them.

Le Cunn also explains this in the [CNN paper](http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/publis/pdf/lecun-98.pdf), page 8, description of LeNet5:

> Layer C5 is a convolutional layer with 120 feature maps. Each unit is
>   connected to a 5x5 neighborhood on all 16 of S4's feature maps. Here
>   because the size of S4 is also 5x5, the size of C5's feature maps is
>   1x1; this amounts to a full connection between S4 and C5.

Answer (score 2):

To any newbie PyTorch user like me - **do not** confuse "fully connected layer" with a "linear layer".

A Linear layer and 1x1 convolutions are the same thing. It took me awhile to understand that there is no such thing as a "fully connected layer" - it's simply a flattening of spatial dimensions into a 1D giant tensor. The flattening causes every element on all spatial locations to be presented as a separate feature map/channel/dimension (whatever you want to call it). Hence, when we apply a *linear layer* on a *flattened tensor*, we get a *fully connected* operation, which obviously, is not the same as a 1x1 convolution.

A `1x1` convolution is simply a weighted summation of input feature maps, in OP's question, 3. O[0] = $\sum_{j=0}^{1} X[j]W_0[j] + b[0]$. Similarly, O[1] = $\sum_{j=0}^{1} X[j]W_1[j] + b[1]$ and O[2] = $\sum_{j=0}^{1} X[j]W_2[j] + b[2]$.

The above 3 equations open up to become $O = W_{2 \times 3}X_{3 \times 1} + b_{2 \times 1}$.

Other answers which claim that a fully-connected layer is simply a **valid** `nxn` convolution layer for an input of size `nxn` is confusing (albeit, correct).