# 1x1 convolutions, equivalence with fully connected layer

Tags: neural-network, convolutional-neural-network

I'm confused by the concept of equating a 1x1 convolution with a fully connected layer. Take the following simple example of a 1x1 convolution of 2 input channels each of size 2x2, and a single output channel.

[image]

The only way I can relate this to fully connected layers is to say that there are 4 fully connected layers, one for each location in the input feature map (inputs and outputs colour coded).

From what I can understand my interpretation is consistent with the [Network in Network](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1312.4400.pdf) paper[Lin et al. 2013] which describe the 1x1 as being equivalent as *cross channel parametric pooling*

> The cross channel parametric pooling layer is also equivalent to a
>   convolution layer with 1x1 con- volution kernel.

I have seen
 [this one from Yann LeCunn](https://www.facebook.com/yann.lecun/posts/10152820758292143) equating 1x1 convolutions to a fully connected layer. And I have read [this](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/12830/how-are-1x1-convolutions-the-same-as-a-fully-connected-layer) answer and I'm just not seeing the equivalence between a 1x1 convolution over an input volume and a single fully connected layer...

Any insight would be appreciated, if you can please relate back to the example above. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The interpretation that the 1d convolution given in the OP can be duplicated with four separate fully-connected layers is correct (see diagram).  Also, in at least some implementations, kernel weights used during a 1x1 convolution can be made trainable the same way weights in a fully-connected layer can be made trainable.  These points made, every fully-connected layer can not be mathematically duplicated by an equivalent 1x1 convolution. This is based on the definition that 1x1 convolution performs a "column-wise dot product" such that every pixel column in a multi-layer feature map is reduced to a single number (pixel).  A fully-connected layer intermixes weights differently from the way weights are intermixed when performing a 1x1 convolution.  In summary, fully connected layers and 1x1 convolutions each have their own use cases -- some overlap among these use cases exists; however, the two are not intended to be mathematically equivalent in a general sense.

[image: Four separate "dense layers" equivalent to the 1x1 convolution in OP]