# Understanding projection layer for BLSTM

Tags: deep-learning, lstm, rnn

In many research papers there are 'projection layers' related to BLSTM layers. For example, from [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1808.02608.pdf):

> "we trained an 8-layer BLSTM encoder including 320 cells in each layer
> and direction, and the linear projection layer with 320 units followed
> by each BLSTM layer"

I can't understand what this means and how it works.

Any help on this topic would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A "projection" is a simple linear/dense layer, that is, a matrix multiplication and a bias vector addition.

It is called projection because you "project" a representation of dimensionality $M$ into a representation space of dimensionality $N$.

Sometimes, especially for sequences or 2D data, these projections are implemented as a convolution of size 1, which [is equivalent](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/45805/14675) to the computations I described above.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I have another question because it's a little bit ambiguous for me, are they used for the dimensionality reduction?

Comment: A projection can be used to decrease the dimensionality of the representation, but it can as well be used to increase the dimensionality.